# My app built with docker-compose up is not updating on Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I have a problem with my app built with docker-compose up. It works fine but whenever I make some changes in the code it never updates in application running on localhost. I need to run the docker-compose up again to see the changes witch is not comfortable at all. And this is only happening on Windows, and it is live updating on Macbook. How can I enable live update on Windows? What could be causing the issue?

Comment: The question is missing critical information. Can you please [edit] the post and share the `docker-compose.yml`, as well as the dockerfile used for the application?

Comment: I can't share any code unfortunately, but I believe it should work as it is working for Mac. Same code which updates changes on Mac and on Windows doesn't.

Comment: Without seeing the `docker-compose.yml` and/or the `Dockerfile`, I fear we cannot help.